# storing output of one file in another file using java

Tags: java, java-8, fileoutputstream

Here in this code some operations are done with using one file **(new.txt)** 
I want to store the output of below code in another file....

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        Arrays.stream(Files.lines(Paths.get("new.txt")).collect(Collectors.joining())
                .replaceAll("^.*?1002|1003(.(?!1002))*$", "\n") // trim leading/trailing non-data
                .split("1003.*?1002")) // split on end-to-start-of-next
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you already kept the entire file contents in memory, a non-stream solution is more straight-forward.

```
String txt = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("in.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
txt = txt.replaceAll(...);
txt = txt.replaceAll(...); // split behavior
Files.write(Paths.get("out.txt"), txt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

---

***Added:***
Though the logic escapes me, the replacements probably should be:

```
finale String EOL = "\n";
txt = txt.replaceAll("^.*?1002|1003(.(?!1002))*$", EOL ) // trim leading/trailing non-data
txt = txt.replaceAll("1003.*?1002", EOL ) // split on end-to-start-of-next
```

Comment: while writing the splitting condition it shows error

Comment: Added my understanding of what should be done in the replaceAlls. Maybe EOL should be "\r\n" if for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could try that:

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
{
    try {
        PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        Arrays.stream(Files.lines(Paths.get("new.txt")).collect(Collectors.joining())
            .replaceAll("^.*?1002|1003(.(?!1002))*$", "\n") // trim leading/trailing non-data
            .split("1003.*?1002"))                        // split on end-to-start-of-next
            .forEachOrdered(os::println);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure what exactly are you looking for. Here is one way of doing it and what I would do.
You can do this directly from the terminal

```
javac myFile.java
java ClassName > myfile.txt
```

This would save your output into a file 'myfile.txt'

Comment: does not working through terminal..if u know from eclipse or netbeans plz tell